# Published movie works fine but loops first movie clip when viewed in browser

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I've been creating this banner:

[url removed]

which accesses an xml document, replaces some texts etc, but as soon as you open it up in a browser (like with the dropbox link I pasted) the banner only loops on the first movie clip.

Put in another way: The banner you see is looping through only the first movie clip.

But the swf file (and the html file) work fine from the local path of my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You swf is throwing a security error, could be causing your issue. The error is as follows:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/647738/barnaland/barnaland-banner_150x600-tilbuinn.swf cannot load data from http://barnaland.is/rev/prices.aspx.
    at barnalandBanner/readXML()
    at barnalandBanner()
```

Comment: That totally makes sense. That's why it only plays the first clip, because I stop the stage at first using stop() and start it with play() once the xml has been loaded.. but of course the first movie clip will start playing none the less! 

How did you find out/notice? 
Great job.

Comment: If you install the browser debug players, you will see errors. Warning though, a lot of Flash content on the web throws errors, so you'll see them everywhere.